# What exactly is a "deep" (or "shallow") scratch on a vitrified floor?

Tags: flooring

I have scratches on my floor made by a sofa having been dragged.

Since I am not a native English speaker, I apologize for the clumsy description of my floor, there is certainly a right word for it I do not know.

This is a floor made of long panels with the following structure:

[image]

The base layer is some kind of hard amalgamate, the wooden one is supposed to be real wood (in one piece, not reconstructed) and the protective layer is what is called in France "vitrification", some kind of polish to protect and harden the floor.

When reading about the techniques to fix such a scratch, most of them make the distinction between "deep" and "shallow" scratches. What does this mean in practice?

The difference is in the solutions: some call for wooden paste + sanding + the protective layer (for the deep scratches) and some other just suggest to rub with wax.

**How would you rate the depth of this scratch?** (this is the same scratch under different angles,  sorry I do not have a camera with a macro lens or anything to actually measure the depth of the scratch)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think the usual term in English is "engineered wood" but it's a bit broad, as some fake (or "reconstructed wood" ) wood floors *also* describe themselves that way (*i.e.* it's marketing, so misleading the customer to think product A and product B are the same is in the interest of the maker of the inferior product...)

Comment: In Britain we call that "laminate flooring". You can fix minor scratches with something like a wax pencil the same colour as the floor. For deep ones like that, you replace. Hopefully you can match the old and new laminate, otherwise that was an expensive scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Shallow would be just a scratch in the protective layer.

Deep is into the wood layer, and that looks likely from your pictures.